# Calculation in CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this extract form a query im writing.
What I want to do is sum only the successful payments
something along the lines of

```
, SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'successful') THEN (SUM(amount) as amt_paid) ELSE 0 END)   AS Successful_Payed
```

Here is the query extract.

```
Select 
   resultdate
 , SUM(amount) as amt_paid
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'successful') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS Successful
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'unsuccessful') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS Unsuccessful
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'tracking') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS Tracking
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'dispute') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS Dispute
From paysoft_results
Group By resultdate
Order By resultdate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change like this

```
Select 
   resultdate
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'successful') THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 
   Successful_Payed
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'successful') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Successful
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'unsuccessful') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unsuccessful
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'tracking') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Tracking
 , SUM(CASE WHEN (LOWER(result) = 'dispute') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dispute
From paysoft_results
Group By resultdate
Order By resultdate
```

Comment: @mornenel Always Welcome